# Error in database connection

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have been working on a project, which is a simple Spring, Hibernate, JSF, MySQL integration; and I run it on Eclipse. The aim of the program is to add a Person(id, first name, last name, gender, age etc.) database on MySQLWorkbench and run it on server. I used Spring4, Hibernate4, Primefaces 5.0.2 and Eclipse Luna as tools.And I constructed the project as maven. 
When I run the program on main, I want to see that a new Person is included in my table.
I used "GRANT ALL ON" and "FLUSH PRIVILEGES" commands for the user I have created, on terminal and received "Query OK" message.
Despite specifying username and password on necessary files, I cannot add a new record to my table.My Project structure is as follows:

[image]

And other files are:

`domain-classes.hbm.xml`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
      "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
          "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class table="testPerson" name="com.hibernate.data.Person">
        <id column="person_id" type="int" name="id">
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="firstName" column="person_firstname" type="string" />
        <property name="lastName" column="person_lastname" type="string" />
        <property name="gender" column="person_gender" type="string" />
        <property name="age" column="person_age" type="int" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

`hibernate.cfg.xml`:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

 <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/PERSONDB</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">fulden2</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">secret_pass</property>
        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <!-- Show SQL -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <!-- Specify session context -->
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <!-- Autocommit -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</property> 
        <!-- Referring Mapping File -->
        <mapping resource="domain-classes.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
 </hibernate-configuration>
```

`applicationContext.xml`:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">
    <!-- Enable Spring Annotation Configuration -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <!-- Scan for all of Spring components such as Spring Service -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.*"></context:component-scan>
    <!-- Create Data Source bean -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/PERSONDB" />
        <property name="username" value="fulden2" />
        <property name="password" value="secret_pass" />
    </bean>
    <!-- Define SessionFactory bean -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- Transaction Manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <!-- Detect @Transactional Annotation -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
</beans>
```

pom.xml:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>test</groupId>
  <artifactId>PersonApp</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>PersonApp</name>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.4</source>
          <target>1.4</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <repositories>
     <repository>
         <id>prime-repo</id>
         <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
         <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
         <layout>default</layout>
     </repository>
   </repositories>
 <dependencies>
  <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
   <!-- Faces Implementation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Faces Library -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Primefaces Version 5 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JSP Library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    <!-- JSTL Library -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Primefaces Theme Library -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
        <artifactId>blitzer</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate library -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- MySQL driver connector library -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.35</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring ORM -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>
</project>
```

Main class:

```
    package com.test;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.hibernate.data.Person;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        System.out.println("CFG and hbm files loaded successfully.");//just to test

        configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

        SessionFactory factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build());

        Session session = factory.openSession();

        Transaction tx = session.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        System.out.println("Transaction began");//just to test

        Person newPerson = new Person();
        newPerson.setFirstName("aa");
        newPerson.setLastName("bbb");
        newPerson.setGender("Male");
        newPerson.setAge(2);

        session.save(newPerson);
        session.flush();

        tx.commit();
        session.close();
        System.out.println("Session closed");//just to test
    }

}
```

Is there an extra step to achieve this database connection?

Or what is my mistake here?

Thanks for any help..

Comment: What error you are getting? Can you show us?

Comment: There isn't any error.main class works as expected.Evenmore, I added some System.out.println lines to main class to check whether it works. Everything seems normal.

Comment: What these sysouts shows you?

Comment: after i run main, it says on the console:
CFG and hbm files loaded successfully./Transaction began/Session closed

Comment: Why don't you put your transaction part in try catch to see how it behaves like here in this example http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_sessions.htm

Just to check for any exceptions.

Comment: i have just added try catch.it runs normal.

Comment: Can you try check by putting session.flush() after tx.commit()? Seen here oddly https://danielniko.wordpress.com/2012/12/03/simple-crud-using-java-hibernate-and-mysql/

Comment: thanks for your suggestions @rakeeee. i have put session.flush() after tx.commit().but nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your session is not getting flushed; might be a glitch in your configuration. It happens many a time for an instance if you have configured OpenSessionInView Filter it changes the default flush mode of your configuration. In the DAO layer check the flushMode `session.getFlushMode()` 
The flush mode should not be `NEVER` or `MANUAL`

If the session is not getting flushed, you db will not be updated. You have to manually flush the session after your transaction by `session.flush()`

Also in the in configuration file just change the property to true from false & check `<property name="connection.autocommit">true</property>`

Comment: thanks for reply.but i already have session.flush() in the main.i also added my main class.can you have a look at it?

Comment: your code looks fine to me. Just check the sql generated in the console.

Comment: Also in the in configuration file just change the property to true from false & check

  <property name="connection.autocommit">true</property>